# Cracking the Beaufort cipher

Tags: classical-cipher, substitution-cipher

Is there any easy way to crack a Beaufort cipher?

We have a Vigenère table, and are trying to guess the keyword.

Any easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes (guessing you are doing the cypher challenge?)

The "[Beaufort Decoder](http://home.earthlink.net/~fpcorr/Beaufort/BeaufortDecoder.html)" is a really good decoding tool (saves you time), then trial and error keywords. Also, the "[Vigenère cracking tool](http://www.simonsingh.net/The_Black_Chamber/vigenere_cracking_tool.html) can be used to find the length of the keyword. Paste the texts you're decoding; the number of the column(s) with the most `x`'s is the length of the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There is an online tool available which cracks vigenere, beauford and autokey ciphers: http://www.guballa.de/pages/geocaching/vigenere-solver.php